# Python Dataframe column of dates - change format to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: python, pandas

df['date'] is the column I am working with.

The data is in the 'date' column is in the day/month/year format, like this:
7/12/2019. How would I modify this column to give me Year-month-day, or 2019-07-12?

This is what I have tried, but still is not working:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(str(df['date']))

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].** _but still is not working_ What does that mean? What are the contents of the column?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.loc[:,'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,'date'], format="%d/%m/%yyyy")
```

Let me know if it works!

EDIT #1

Since, the "date" column has mixed formats, try:

```
def date_format(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        try:
            df.loc[index, row['date']] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[index, row['date']], format="%d/%m/%yyyy")
        except ValueError as e:
            df.loc[index, row['date']] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[index, row['date']], format="%m/%d/%yyyy")
    return df
```

Comment: Hi, I removed the extra ) at the very end, and it ran, but with the following:  ValueError: time data '12/25/2019' does not match format '%d/%m/%yyyy' (match)

Comment: This means that the column "date" has not got a fixed format. There are some dates with format - m/d/yyyy.

Comment: If there are only two different formats then my solution should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) if you need to convert `datetime` to other formats (but note that then dtype of column will be `object` (`string`)):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '26/1/2016', 1: '26/1/2016'}})
print (df)
         DOB
0  26/1/2016 
1  26/1/2016

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DOB)
print (df)
         DOB
0 2016-01-26
1 2016-01-26

df['DOB1'] = df['DOB'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print (df)
         DOB        DOB1
0 2016-01-26  01/26/2016
1 2016-01-26  01/26/2016
```